# Vue.js returning html element from method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I've been trying to return html elements from a method and i figured i could use v-html for that purpose (Not sure if there's a better way) but i think i hit a roadblock with backtick templates and string interpolation. I get an error saying "cannot read property color of undefined" eventhough the imported object is visible and i can see it when i console.log (and all the keys for the object exist) So i'm assuming it's something to do with template string. i also tried using computed properties instead of method but then vue gave an error for v-if or v-for when i used {{computedValue}} in the template. Is my way of using v-html and string literal correct? The exact same thing works if i declare the logos in data as a state but i don't want to do it as it reshares some logic

```
template<template>
  <div>
    <v-app>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="initiativeData"
        :footer-props="{
          'items-per-page-options': [10, 20, 30, -1],
          'show-current-page': true,
          'show-first-last-page': true,
        }"
      >
        <template v-slot:[`item.goals`]="{ item }">
          <ul v-for="types in item.goals" :key="types" v-html=icons(types)>
          </ul>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import logos from "./components/logos"

export default {
  name: "App",
    methods:{
    icons(types){
      console.log("section is",)
      return `<li v-if="${types} in ${logos}">
                 <v-icon small :color="${logos[types].color}">${logos[types].icon}</v-icon>
              </li>
             `
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

And my logos file is basically something like this;

```
export default {
  sectionFABStylesMap:{
    Phoenix: {
      label: 'Phoenix',
      color: colors.section.phoenix,
      icon: 'fab fa-phoenix',
    },
    Atlanta: {
      label: 'Atlanta',
      color: colors.section.atlanta,
      icon: 'fas fa-window-maximize',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`v-html` sets the element's `innerHTML` to the specified string as-is, and that's not compiled by Vue, so you can't use Vue syntax/components in the string.

Instead, you could make `logos.sectionFABStylesMap` a data property:

```js
import logos from "./components/logos"

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      logos: logos.sectionFABStylesMap,
    }
  }
}
```

and move the markup from the string into the template:

```html
<template v-slot:[`item.goals`]="{ item }">
  <ul v-for="types in item.goals" :key="types">
    <li v-if="types in logos">
      <v-icon small :color="logos[types].color">{{logos[types].icon}}</v-icon>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```